# My dashboard app disorients in different screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-size

I'm a budding android developer, I'm creating an android app which contains a dashboard. I designed my dashboard according to my NEXUS 7 tablet. Now when I run that same app in a 5 inch android phone all the alignments where disoriented. Is there any solution? so that it will look's the same in all screen sizes.
Below is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#ffffffff">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0.0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SpO2"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/four_five"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        android:textColor="#ff7a0000" />
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="45% "
           android:textSize="100dp"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/four_five"
           android:textColor="#ffef00b9" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spo2"/>
   </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0.0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:text="STEPS"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/text_view3"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_view3"
                android:id="@+id/text_view4"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="1258"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="40dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/steps"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0.0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_view5"
                android:text="bpm"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_view6"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_view5"
                android:text="5000"
                android:textSize="60dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bpm"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0.0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="KCal"
                android:id="@+id/text_view7"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_view8"
                android:text="9876"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_view7"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/kcal"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:background="@drawable/centre_button"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/main_centre_button"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="99°C"

    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/text_view9"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome :)
Let's start off with 20 dp as an example.
20 dp is 20 dp no matter if the screen is a tablet, phone or giant tv screen.
So the overall problem is your using fixed measurements for variable screen sizes. The solution is to create different layouts for different devices like

Regular phone in portrait mode = layout-portrait

Regular phone in landscape mode = layout-land

Tablet in portrait = layout-large-portrait

Tablet in landscape = layout-large-land

You can find much more info on how to support different screen sizes below and don't feel too bad. It wasn't but a year or two ago that I was a newbie also.

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.htmll

AND

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html